# Map not showing on emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I am trying to implement a simple google maps demo. It shows perfectly on the browser after it asks for permission. On tizen emulator the map doesn't show and i get a location icon blinking on the top right.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>map demo</title>

    <style>
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: grey;
      }
    </style>





</head>
<body>

    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>



<script>
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    console.log('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude  + 'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude);
    var uluru = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};

      var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});

}, function(error) {
    console.error('GPS error occurred');
});

  // The location of Uluru

  // The map, centered at Uluru

}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MYKEYHERE&callback=initMap">
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

and this is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/CoTakwira" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <access origin="http://googleapis.com" subdomains="true"></access>
    <access origin="http://gstatic.com" subdomains="true"></access>
    <access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true"></access>
    <tizen:application id="TIounxF6Sw.CoTakwira" package="TIounxF6Sw" required_version="3.0"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>CoTakwira</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/location"/>
    <tizen:profile name="mobile"/>
</widget>
```

This is what i'm getting on tizen emulator

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check emulator network settings

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps described in the tip document here in ***[this link](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/nearby-places-search)***. Also please try adding below line in the project's config.xml file. Hope it'll help.

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I followed the documentation to the T and i still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please add these in your **config.xml**

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<tizen:allow-navigation>*<tizen:allow-navigation/>
<tizen:content-security-policy>self</tizen:content-security-policy>
```

[Check this](https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/web-application/application-development-process/setting-project-properties) to know more about defining External Access Policies.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I added that but unfortunately it doesn't do the trick

Comment: Would you please check the network setting of emulator?